# Cutting curved recess

Tags: technique

I am an amateur level woodworker, looking to cut a curved recess into a piece of wood, which I will then be using as a "back" to display a drinks bottle, in a similar style to the picture below, but with the back curve of the bottle nestling into the recess shape in the wood.  The curved recess therefore needs to be the same approx size and curve as the length of the bottle back.  Any tips or suggestions much appreciated.

[image: Bottle display]

Comment: What tools do you have available and how perfect does the fit need to be?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Superficially this looks fairly simple but is actually surprisingly difficult to do.... to the point that many woodworkers (including some experienced amateurs and pros) would either just avoid it, even for a one-off, or only do it if they were doing multiples — making the building of a router sled worth it. As @Max has asked it's very important for us to know what tooling your have available, and your level of commitment — for one you could do this the old-school way, by hand. i.e. by carving. Not easy, and requires the right tools such as one or more gouges.

Comment: Oh and P.S. how deeply would you like the bottle to sit into the wood backer board, and what depth would you accept if this is too difficult or impractical? Speaking of compromises, had you thought of just cutting a shape into the wood for the bottle to nestle into, and would this be an okay option?

Comment: Or going with compromises, is making some sort of mold or casting in epoxy an option? If the whole thing gets painted anyways, this might be easier. Cast in epoxy or something like that, cut square, make square cutout in wood, paint over. Or even make the epoxy a feature by coloring it etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the really helpful responses, and the time and thought that has gone into them, including the video links. Definitely given me some ideas. Just to expand on my original question, this is intended to be a one-off project for me and I'm hoping to use the various tools that are available at a weekly woodworking club that I have just joined. I'll probably start the project in 2-3 weeks time, and will post a picture of the result. Thank you again, very much appreciated.

Comment: If you'll take a moment to take the [tour], you'll see that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up arrow next to every answer that helped you and the check mark next to the answer that helped the most.

Answer (score 3):

> The curved recess therefore needs to be the same approx size and curve as the length of the bottle back.

If you're just making one, get some gouges and just carve the recess. Lay out the outline, maybe use a drill press to drill holes to the desired depths on a grid, and then get to work.

If you're making many, either buy a small CNC router to do the work, or buy or build a [router duplicator](https://www.woodsmithplans.com/plan/carving-duplicator/) so that once you've made one, you can quickly make as many copies as you want.

If you're making a small-ish number, maybe visit your local maker space or find a friend who has a suitable CNC.

Comment: I upvoted, but is a CNC really a viable recommendation? I know they've come down loads in price in just the past 1-2 years so cost may not be a barrier. Putting aside whether the CNC itself is actually capable of the milling operation (sufficient z-axis travel?), isn't the programming side of this non-trivial? A good fit requires two different compound curves, rather than being a simple partial cylinder

Comment: @Graphus Whether it makes financial sense to buy a CNC obviously depends on how many of these things the OP needs to make; if you're doing this stuff as a business I think it'd be irresponsible not to own a CNC. The cost *is* coming down, but you also have to consider that the machine works automatically. You could take a rough board, surface just the back side, and let the machine do everything else except some sanding and finishing.

Comment: @Graphus As for "programming," I guess it's nontrivial in the sense that you need to be comfortable with a CAD/CAM package like Fusion 360, but there's no actual computer programming (in the sense of writing code) involved. Forming a hollow that's the shape of a wine bottle would be easy, and any actual CNC router (as opposed to just an engraver) should be able to handle the depth, judging by the thickness of the board in the OP's photo.

Comment: I'm old enough that G-code was a thing when I first heard of CNC but I did mean using something like Fusion 360 rather than coding. And from so much I've heard over the years Fusion 360 is not exactly regarded as easy to pick up..... "Fusion 360" and "learning curve" seeming to *frequently* be in the same sentence ^_^ Obviously if the intent was to pick up a CNC for ongoing commercial use then learning something like 360 would be a necessity.

Comment: @Graphus G-code is still thing -- you just don't usually write it yourself. There's no CAD software worth using that doesn't require a bit of effort to learn, just as proper drafting requires more a lot more thought than just jotting down a quick sketch. Fusion 360 is probably one of the easier packages to learn; I think you hear more people asking for help mainly because it's extremely popular (it's free, and widely used in 3D printing). There are obviously far fewer people trying to learn more expensive packages like SolidWorks etc.

Answer (score 3):

If I was making 1 or 2, I'd take my angle grinder with a flapper disk (sand paper flaps) and just grind it out.  Would probably start with a practice piece, takes a little getting used to the first time.  But a 4 1/2" angle grinder should make a decently close arc for a wine bottle.

[image]

As Graphus pointed out, while this is probably the fastest way to get what you are looking for, some safety precautions should be considered and accounted for.

1. This throws a lot of sawdust into the air so you will want a well ventilated area and a dust mask, maybe some safety googles as well.
2. This is a high speed torque handheld machine.  you want to make sure the piece you are working on is clamped down well so it won't move.  The piece can be spun and shot across a work shop in the blink of an eye.
3. Once again it is a high speed torque machine that you hold and control with your hands.  start with a test piece and get used to it.  make sure you have the reversible handle attached and use it as well, it makes a big difference in being able to control where the grinder travels.

Comment: This could sure work well, and is probably the fastest of the available suggestions (and then some!). But I think it could do with some safety notes on workholding given the OP's stated level.

Comment: @Graphus very true!  should have thought of that myself  I'll add some in

Comment: Yes it was very much #2 that I had in my head; I should have also been thinking of #1 so that's *at least* as important. Nice update, +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is "cut a cove" in the wood. There are a multitude of techniques for this, but the most available is likely to involve a table saw. If you don't have a table saw, you could use a router. Either one of these power tools will likely have a multitude of videos available on YouTube showing how it can be done.

#### Table Saw

Cove cutting on a table saw requires moving the wood at an angle relative to the blade. Instead of the axis of motion being parallel to the axis of cutting, it will be at an angle usually between 15 and 40 degrees (could be more, could be less, depending on the "curve" you want). This will require a temporary fence set at an angle, and a great deal of fiddling to get all the positioning stuff exactly right.

Here is a video demonstrating cutting a cove with a table saw:  https://youtu.be/vVlvwJelz9s

And here is a page that will help you print a chart of settings for cove cutting: https://woodgears.ca/cove/calculate.html (There is a link from that page to a how-to article on the same site for more details.)

Cove cutting on a table saw is very sensitive to the tooth bevel, if any. If you are using a dedicated ATB saw blade, you might want to change it out for a different bevel. A FTG blade, or ATBR/"Combo" blade, you will probably be okay. If you are just using the blade that came with the saw, it's likely a combo blade.

The take-away from that is that you should run some test cuts, and you should **finish** at least one of your test pieces, to ensure that you know how deep to cut and how much depth to leave alone so you can sand away any tooth marks.

#### Router

There are three ways to cut a cove with a router. The first is to make the entire cut with a dedicated bit. These bits are usually pretty small - the overall width is probable limited to a bit over an inch, max. (Here's a [1" bit](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/9d6f4676-90b5-44de-8e80-d84cb3e28744_1.97616853cb4b74bfb1519ddf7cc6f9d7.jpeg), notice the head/shank ratio.) These are okay for "fluting" but probably not what you want for gentle coves.

The second way is with an edging cove bit. This bit comes with a guide bearing at the end of the bit and is intended to ride along a smooth edge, cutting a cove shape along the edge. (Here's [an example](https://www.rockler.com/media/catalog/product/cache/e48bc02676090cdee0f5e795d38346da/2/1/21522-01-1000.jpg). ) Because these bits can be quite wide, you will generally find them with a thicker shank and you will have to slow down the router speed when using them. (If you have a "one speed" router, you might be able to find an external speed control for a plug-in unit, or you might have to buy or borrow a different router. **This is no joke:** using a wide router bit at too high a speed can result in a really angry piece of sharpened steel flying at your face. Don't do it!) My suggestion with this setup would be to split your wood in two, use the cove bit on matching sides, and then glue the pieces back together. Be aware that for best results with these bits, you'll definitely want a router table setup.

Finally, a third way would be to build some sort of sled or jig to let you "swing" the entire router body like a pendulum. You would then use a simple square bit to do the cutting, and move the entire thing along the wood a little at a time. This would let you do the cutting on any kind of router (almost - unusual body shapes might make it hard to build an appropriate jig, or to balance it) with just a cheap, common bit.

Comment: The cutout required is *not* a simple cove, so a cove cut on the TS or a simple milling operation with a bit of matching radius won't form the shape required.

Comment: @Graphus From the original question: _"...The curved recess therefore needs to be the same approx size and curve as the length of the bottle back...."_  It seems that the neck of the bottle is not included.  How is this not a cove cut?

Comment: @gnicko, because the top and bottom compound curves aren't the same. Obviously the 'main body' of the recess *is* a cove, but the ends are different; and one of them is impossible to form by either method.

Comment: @Graphus I think you're assuming a lot that simply isn't stated in the original question. What do you mean by "top" and "bottom" curves?

Comment: @gnicko, um, this is kinda feeling like an episode of the Twilight Zone. You do know what compound curves are right? If you do then just think about the (not bilaterally symmetrical) shape of a wine bottle. If you're having trouble visualising this put a pile of flour on your counter, press a wine bottle into it and see the depression left behind after you lift it out. And if you're *still* having trouble grokking this turn the bottle end for end and see how it doesn't fit into the depression any more!

Comment: @Graphus  Well, if nothing else you're always amusing!  ;)